# How to use the map operator in rxjs within an angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular7, rxjs6

My code compiles and everything is working fine, but my IDE (Visual Studio Code) shows the following error message and I'm unable to deploy my app (with ng build --prod):

> ERROR in src/app/training/training.service.ts(61,46): error TS2339:
>   Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/training/training.service.ts(62,50): error TS2339: Property
>   'duration' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/training/training.service.ts(63,50): error TS2339: Property
>   'calories' does not exist on type '{}'.

I import the map operator like this:

```
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and use it like this:

```
...
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
            duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
            calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
          };
        });
      })
    )
...
```

My interface looks like:

```
export interface Exercise {
id: string;
name: string;
duration: number;
calories: number;
date?: Date;
state?: 'completed' | 'cancelled' | null;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *type* does the method that uses this code returns?

Comment: It is a subscription to a firebase database/collection and fetches the data from there. I added the used interface to my question. I have the feeling that it is due to the second nested map function. Because it is not the rxjs operator, but the normal Javascript method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fool Typescript, you might do this:

```
doc => {

    let result: any = doc.payload.doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            name: result.name,
            duration: result.duration,
            calories: result.calories
          };
```

Comment: That's how it works, but why do I get an error message with my version? The import is correct and I also use the pipe syntax. Does this really only have to do with my IDE?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your import, syntax, or IDE. The data() function might    have a wrong signature, or do not signature defined in Typescript.  Typescript then would not allow you to use data().id. Redefine it as any let typescript to skip type check here.